# Python Large Data Set - PyTable HDF5 with Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pytables, hdf

I have a very large file saved as abn hdf file. I also have some data in a python dataframe that I would like to look up in the hdf file by an unique id.

Is there an easy way to basically join them? I saw the example for the where function but it didn't seem easy to use with a large number of values to look up.

Comment: please share some code, perhaps even a before and after picture

Comment: are both datasets the same kind (columns, datatypes etc.)? If yes, do you want to append that table to the one saved as hdf file? If not, do you just want to save it as hdf5 file? Please show what you already have.